# Why "+=" operator not works when more than one string is added?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, c++17, string-concatenation

when I'm trying to concatenate a string variable with more than one string with this operator(+=) it rises an error.

**NOTE:**
The other two strings should not be stored in a variable.

```
string str="hello";
    
str = str + " " + "world";
cout << str << endl;    //hello world
    
str += " " + "world";
cout << str;            //error              //why?
                        //*but in java it works*
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to add two string literals. The expression:

```
" " + "world"
```

in C++ is of type

```
const char* + const char*
```

`const char*` has no overloaded operator+. But standard strings do overload operator+ for addition with string literals, e.g:

```
operator+(std::string const& lhs, const char *rhs);
```

and that's why your first expression succeeds: the `str` object gets the ball rolling:

```
str + " " + "World" 
= std::string + const char* + const char*
= std::string + const char*
= std::string
```

to make it work use

```
str += " world"
// or
str += std::string(" ") + "world";
// the last one is to better explain what's going on,
```